# QScrollArea C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется виджет, в котором несколько гроупбоксов. В каждом гроупбоксе qscrollarea. Туда я добавляю лейбл с какой-то информацией. Когда этой информации в строчке много, то появляется скролл, что логично. Вопрос в следующем:

Как добиться результата, когда при запуске программы скролла вообще нет, вместо этого виджет самостоятельно, исходя из количества в нем объектов(речь про гроупбокс) расширился. Но когда я начинаю менять руками размер виджета, то появлялась бы qsrollarea

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Хотелось бы прояснить, что такое "гроупбокс"?  В английском слово `group` читается `[gru:p]` и переводится как "группа".  Слово, звучащее как "гроуп" (grope) обозначает [нечто другое](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?ll1=1&ll2=2&s=grope&l2=2)

Comment: @NowhereMan QGroupBox

Comment: см. свойства verticalScrollBarPolicy/horizontalScrollBarPolicy и значение ScrollBarAsNeeded

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev пробовал, но это не помогает.

Comment: может быть `QWidget::adjustSize()`?

Comment: @PavelGridin   К сожалению, adjustsize тоже не работает. Наверное, как то через resizeEvent можно пробовать это сделать, но я не умею, буду разбираться

Comment: выложите ui файл может и подскажут что-то